# Adding windows to faces of complex geometry

Tags: geometry, windows

Is there a faster and cleaner way to add windows to a complex mesh with angles? I'm trying to re-create a modern building [image: See building cut in-between individual windows]

Whilst I'm able to recreate the geometry I'm struggling to find a way to 'line' the faces with windows accurately - is there a more precise and efficient way to do this? [image: My geometry which needs to lined with windows.]

Comment: Hello, it all depends on what you're trying to do, you could simply project an image on the surface of your object so that you wouldn't need to add any extra geometry, if you want to add horizontal edges, you could create a plane with horizontal and vertical edges and use the Knife Project tool

Comment: Hiya, sorry I didn't outline correctly - I am trying to add physical geometry to this, or at least the frame of windows - using the knife tool - can I space out cuts to equal length of eachother?

Comment: sure, you can create some loopcuts, then bevel these loopcuts, or create one window then array it with the Array modifer and use the result as the cutter object of the Knife Project tool

Comment: Is there a way to use the knife tool in such a way where it creates multiple cuts?

Comment: no, Knife tool only produces one edge

Comment: I can't use the loop cut tool as it's not a quad model, each layer of this model curves differently, so I'll have to manually cut each loop into the model?

Comment: No, as I say you can use the Knife Project tool, which is something else than the Knife tool, it allows you to poject edges onto the surface of a face, you just need to prepare the kind of grid

Answer (score 1):

To project topology on a surface you can use the *Knife Project* tool:

Prepare the cutter object (the one that will have the window shapes), remove its faces:

[image]

Select the building object, switch to *Edit* mode and front view, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>LMB</kbd> on the cutter object, go into *Mesh > Knife Project*:

[image]

Result, the cutter object has cut new edge loops on the surface of your building:

[image]